# Extended euclidean algorithm using table

Tags: calculus, euclidean-algorithm

I have to solve gcd$(133,99)=d$,  $d = ax + by$ using the extended euclidean algorithm. I understand a part of it but this table we have to use/fill out confuses me a bit.

I get bit confused at step $4$. I sort of get the subtraction column I'm guessing $()$ set the precedence so $4$th step subtraction becomes $99 - ((133 - 99) \cdot 2)$

So first evaluate $(133\cdot 0 + 99\cdot 1)$, then evaluate $(133\cdot 1 - 99 \cdot (-1))$, then evaluate $99 - (34 \cdot 2)$ and finally $99 - 68 = 31$.

This is bit confusing but I guess understandable what confuses me the most is where I go wrong in the combined expression column on step $3$ seems I made the correct assumption however on step $4$ the result does not equal $31$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this layout for the algorithm will help:

[image]

Comment: Nevermind got it. Thank you so very much finally understand it this form is much clearer but I know how it works out now in my table.